# how to check a math expression in a string Python

Tags: python

I have a math expression in a string.

So,how can i check **is math expression right** ?

Maybe there are some ways to do that using Python libraries without creating own functional?

**Examples:**

```
exp = "(5+5)-(5)+(-2)" #True
exp = "(5+5)/2-1" #True
exp = "(5+5)/(3-1)" #True
exp = "(5+5)/(3-1" #False
exp = "5+" #False
exp = "(5+5)/()" #False
exp = "(a+b)/5" #False (only numbers)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `eval` function in pandas

```
import pandas as pd
exp = "(5+5)-(5)+(-2)"
pd.eval(exp)
```

If you intend on using expressions like `"(a+b)/5"` make sure you define the variables like this

```
a = 1
b = 2
exp = "(a+b)/5"
pd.eval(exp)
```

else the snippet will yield the following error:

```
UndefinedVariableError: name 'a' is not defined
```

You can try using this function

```
def ismath(exp):
    try:
        result = pd.eval(exp)
        return True
    except Exception:
        return False

ismath("(5+5)-(5)+(-2)") # Returns True
ismath("(5+5)-(5)+(a)") # Returns False
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Luke has suggested, `eval()` can be used, but I think it's important to expand due to the risks associated with the use of `eval` - especially with user-controlled input.

## 2 big reasons to pre-filter input with a regex pattern

1. In order to filter out expressions that contain anything other than valid mathematical expressions (without variables), you will want to first perform a regex filter, only passing to `eval()` strings which contain only characters that are valid in a math-context *(which was part of your question)*
2. The *second* reason to use a regex, is that `eval()` can be very dangerous when users are able to inject arbitrary values as direct input. By limiting to only the characters valid in a math equation, your risk is reduced significantly

## The Regex itself

You can validate that inputs match a pattern along the lines of: `r'^[\d+-/*()]+$'` ([example here](https://regex101.com/r/azb71x/1))

While the version above wouldn't account for syntactically incorrect operations (e.g. `"(5+5)/(3-1"`, `"5+"` or `"(5+5)/()"`), you should be able to play with it to improve filtering.

... or just catch the errors from `eval()` that result from invalid math

## More on security

[This page](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval) gives some more context/examples of the risks of `eval()` as well as some ways to mitigate.

## tl;dr

1. Use a regex to limit input to `eval()` to only strings made up exclusively or math characters
2. make the function call like so: `eval(expr, {}, {})` such that the eval function will not have access to the program's `global` and `local` variables (which it doesn't need in the first place).